# Dynamic Table View within Static Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm fairly new into Swift programming and right now I'm implementing a dynamic table view within a static table view's cell. I know there are plenty of solutions on stackoverflow already but I realised that most of them are in Obj-C which I'm not very familiar with it yet.

Basically, I have a TableView that is set as dynamic in one of the cell of a static table view which is part of the main table view controller. The problem I am having now is there doesn't seem to be a way to implement the data source functions without declaring them for the static table view. I have declared an `@IBOutlet` for the dynamic table (let's call it `dynamicTableView` in this scenario).

I have managed to get the `override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)` working by returning `1` if the `tableView` is not `dynamicTableView` as in the following code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if tableView == dynamicTableView {
            return data.count
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
    }
```

However, the problem I am having now is implementing the `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. I have no idea what to be returned if the `tableView` parameter is not `dynamicTableView`, but for the static table view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == dynamicTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dynamic", for: indexPath) as! dynamicTableViewCell

            cell.update(data[indexPath.row]) // A helper function declared in the dynamicTableViewCell.swift

            return cell
        }
        else {
            // What to return here?
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Edit: What I meant was I can't seem to have a `cellForRowAt` data source function that does not affect my static table view.

Comment: Show us what kind of UI you want to build

Comment: The UI is basically the page of an app in the App Store (which I believe is a static table view) with the review portion being replaced by a dynamic table view that populated based on the number of reviews submitted.

Comment: you have to return the cell containing your dynamic tableview in the else condition inside cellForRowAt method

Comment: hmm the what about the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a value in numberForRows then you have to retutn a cell like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == bloggerReviewTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dynamic", for: indexPath) as! dynamicTableViewCell

            cell.update(data[indexPath.row]) // A helper function declared in the dynamicTableViewCell.swift

            return cell
        }
        else {
            // What to return here?
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "other", for: indexPath) as! OtherTableCell
               return cell 
        }
  }
```

//

but if the return is zero then there is no need for the if statement inside cellForRowAt as it won't be called for the other table

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! However, that's not what I'm quite looking for. The else statement in this case is for the condition when the data source function is ran for the static table view. Hence, there isn't any identifier or external TableViewCell declared.

Comment: tried to remove the dataSource protocol set for the static table?

Comment: I do still need the dataSource protocol for my dynamicTable though

Comment: Are they nested tables or 2 tables in the same VC ? , if 2 then remove the dataSource for the static only

Comment: Hmm I’m not really sure what’s the difference. Basically the dynamic table view is within the cell of a static table view.

Answer (score 0):

If the static tableview cells are fairly distinct, they can be individually subclassed. 
The dynamic tableview/collectionview can be added in required subclass of static tableview cell.

//class for static tableview

```
 let reviewCellId = "reviewCell"

    class StaticTableClass: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //register static cell classes
        tableView.register(ReviewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reviewCellId)
        //..

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reviewCellId, for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
  }
```

Create a separate ReviewCell class which will contain the dynamic UITableView like so.

This way one class will handle methods of only one tableview.

```
 class ReviewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        lazy var dynamicTableView: UITableView = {
            let tv = UITableView()
            tv.delegate = self
            tv.dataSource = self
        }()

        override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

            setupViews()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        func setupViews() {
            addSubview(dynamicTableView)

            dynamicTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "dynamicCellId")
        }

        // add further tableview methods in here
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        }
}
```